# UITextfield design in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uitextfield

I am designing Login form in swift. I failed to design as per my client requirement. Kindly guide me. My design pattern is in the image.

I know how to give shadow effect in swift. But, I don't know this type of effects in fields.

[image: LOGIN IMAGE]

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 170, 100));
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor();
var textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(5, 10, 150, 37));
textField.text = "Some Text";
textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor();
textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 18.0;
textField.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 37));
textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;

var textField1 = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(5, 50, 150, 37));
textField1.text = "Some Text";
textField1.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor();
textField1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
textField1.layer.cornerRadius = 18.0;
textField1.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 37));
textField1.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;

view.addSubview(textField);
view.addSubview(textField1);
self.view.addSubview(view);
```

Comment: How to do that Rounded rectangle view which having some effect in that image?? @ yashwanth

Comment: using "textField.layer.cornerRadius = 18.0;" statement

Comment: Rounded corner no issues. But, that two fields are just inside, when compare with outer view. How to do that? @ yashwanth

Comment: Yeah got through my code u will understand.Add two textfields inside another view."self.view.addSubview(view);" does this for you.

Comment: how to inner shadow to that field? @ yashwanth